# Changing the order of integration of $ \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{\arccos x}e^{\sin x} \,dx\,dy $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

> Evaluate $ \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{\arccos x}e^{\sin x} \,dx\,dy $.

By inspection, $ \int e^{\sin x}\,dx $ is not possible or is difficult. My initial plan was to change the order of integration so that $e^{\sin x}$ will just be treated as a constant, I represented the integral as
$$ \int \int_{A} e^{\sin x} \,dy\,dx .$$
However, I am having trouble with how to get the new basic region I denoted as $A$.

Comment: If you use $u=\arccos(x)$, then the integral becomes $-\int_{0}^{u}e^{\sin(\cos(t))}\sin(t)dt$

Comment: Do you mean for the upper bound of integraton to be $\arccos y$?

Comment: @rogerl the problem was given to us that way which is very peculiar. Upon reading your comment I tried making the upper bound of integration to arccos y and it was pretty easy to evaluate. I hope that the instructor only had a typographical error and arccos x was not intended to be the upper bound of integration of this problem.

Comment: The problem as written simply makes no sense.